# Boolean Algebra: Self-dual Boolean Function $g(x) = \lnot f(\lnot x)$

Tags: induction, boolean-algebra

Q) For $x \in \{0,1\}$, let $\lnot x$ denote the negation of $x$, that is $$\lnot \,  x = \begin{cases}1 & \mbox{iff } x = 0\\ 0 & \mbox{iff } x = 1\end{cases}$$.
If $x \in \{0,1\}^n$, then $\lnot \, x$ denotes the component wise negation of $x$; that is: $$(\lnot \, x)_i=\left (\lnot \, x_i \mid i \in [1..n] \right )$$

Consider a circuit $C$, computing a function $f: \{0,1\}^{n} \to \{0,1\}$ using AND $(\land)$, OR $(\lor)$,and NOT $(\lnot)$ gates. Let $D$ be the circuit obtained from $C$ by replacing each AND gate by an OR gate and replacing each OR gate by an AND. Suppose $D$ computes the function $g$.   Then it is given as $g(x) = \lnot f(\lnot x).$ It is the definition of self-dual boolean function and I was trying to prove it using induction on '$n$'.
**Base Step :** For $n=2$, assuming boolean variables $x_1,x_2 \in \{0,1\}$ and circuit $C$ has one or more than $1$ AND gate then $f(x) = f(x_1,x_2) = x_1.x_2$. Now, $\lnot f(\lnot x) = \lnot f(\lnot x_1,\lnot x_2) = \lnot(\lnot x_1 . \lnot x_2) = x_1 + x_2$ which is same as output of OR gate with input $x_1,x_2$ and it is circuit $D$ with one or more OR gate.
Similarly, I can show it for Circuit $C$ with one or more OR gate.
 **Inductive Hypothesis :**  For $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ and $x_1,x_2,.....,x_n \in \{0,1\},$ $g(x) = \lnot f(\lnot x).$
**Inductive Step :** If circuit cotains only AND gates then if we add one more boolean variable $x_n$ and one AND gate then output of circuit C is $f(x) = x_1.x_2.....x_n.x_{n+1}$. So, here, according to De-Morgan's Law for $n+1$ boolaen variables $g(x) = \lnot f(\lnot x).$ is true. Similarly, it is true for OR gates. Now, when circuit $C$ has combination of AND and OR gates then how to proceed it ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Please note that your circuit can be arbitrarily complex, even with just $2$ variables and just a bunch of AND gates, e.g.   you can have a circuit corresponding to $(x_1 \cdot x_2) \cdot (x_2 \cdot (x_1 \cdot x_1))$

So, don't try to prove this by induction on $n$, but rather try to prove this based on how the circuit is structured. Thus, the base case is a single variable, while the inductive step is taking any two circuits and applying either an AND or an OR to their outputs.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me, Is it like, Suppose, for one circuit we have, output as : $f_1(x_1,x_2,....,x_p)$ and for another circuit, we have output as : $f_2(y_1,y_2,....,y_q)$. So, according to hypothesis, $g_1(x_1,x_2,....,x_p) = \lnot f_1(\lnot x_1, \lnot x_2, ....\lnot x_p)$ and $g_2(y_1,y_2,....,y_q) = \lnot f_2(\lnot y_1, \lnot y_2, ....\lnot y_q)$.

Comment: Now, if both circuits are connected by AND gate, then output will be  $f(x_1,x_2,.....,x_p,y_1,y_2,...y_q) =  f_1(x_1,x_2,....,x_p).f_2(y_1,y_2,....,y_q).$. Now, $\lnot f(\lnot x) = \lnot f(\lnot x_1,\lnot x_2,.....,\lnot x_p,\lnot y_1,\lnot y_2,...\lnot y_q) = \lnot ((\lnot f_1(\lnot x_1,\lnot x_2,....,\lnot x_p)).(\lnot f_2(\lnot y_1, \lnot y_2,....,\lnot y_q))) =\lnot f_1(\lnot x_1,\lnot x_2,.....,\lnot x_p) + \lnot f_2(\lnot y_1,\lnot y_2,.....,\lnot y_q)   =g_1(x_1,x_2,.....,x_p)+ g_2(y_1,y_2,....,y_q) = g(x)$

Comment: * ¬((¬f1(¬x1,¬x2,....,¬xp)).(¬f2(¬y1,¬y2,....,¬yq))) = g1(x1,x2,.....,xp)+ g2(y1,y2,....,yq)=g(x)

Comment: @ankit Exactly!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Bram28

Comment: @ankit You're welcome! Glad I could help :)